# How to use ddbmock with dynamodb-mapper?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, boto, amazon-dynamodb

Can someone please explain how to set up [dynamodb_mapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dynamodb-mapper) (together with [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto)?) to use [ddbmock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ddbmock/1.0.1) with sqlite backend as [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)-replacement for functional testing purposes?

Right now, I have tried out "plain" boto and managed to get it working with ddbmock (with sqlite) by starting the ddbmock server locally and connect using boto like this:

```
db = connect_boto_network(host='127.0.0.1', port=6543)
```

..and then I use the db object for all operations against the database. However, dynamodb_mapper uses this way to get a db connection:

```
conn = ConnectionBorg()
```

As I understand, it uses boto's default way to connect with (the real) DynamoDB. So basically I'm wondering if there is a (preferred?) way to get ConnectionBorg() to connect with my local ddbmock server, as I've done with boto above? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

### Library Mode

In library mode rather than server mode:

```
import boto
from ddbmock import config
from ddbmock import connect_boto_patch

# switch to sqlite backend
config.STORAGE_ENGINE_NAME = 'sqlite'
# define the database path. defaults to 'dynamo.db'
config.STORAGE_SQLITE_FILE = '/tmp/my_database.sqlite'

# Wire-up boto and ddbmock together
db = connect_boto_patch()
```

Any access to dynamodb service via boto will use ddbmock under the hood.

### Server Mode

If you still want to us ddbmock in server mode, I would try to change `ConnectionBorg._shared_state['_region']` in the really beginning of test setup code:

```
ConnectionBorg._shared_state['_region'] = RegionInfo(name='ddbmock', endpoint="localhost:6543")
```

As far as I understand, any access to dynamodb via any `ConnectionBorg` instance after those lines will use ddbmock entry point.

This said, I've never tested it. I'll make sure authors of ddbmock gives an update on this.

Comment: I confirm the "library mode" procedure. Indeed, this is unit-tested this way. For the "server mode", I have to admit that I never actually tried it. Nonetheless, ``ConnectionBorg()._region = ...`` will do the same will being nicer to read.

Comment: Btw, the exact field name is ``_region`` (with a leading '_')

Comment: BTW, changing `ConnectionBorg()._region` will not change the shared state.